# Are there DNS leaks with the system proxy setting?

Tags: security, dns

I'm using a system-wide proxy to browse the Internet. Are there any DNS leaks with that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. However the leaks are coming from the proxy server and not from your computer.

If the proxy server is being used by many people it would be somewhat harder (although not impossible) to link the DNS leaks back to you.

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  **;-)**